# Pass data from sqlite database to achrtengine

Tags: android, achartengine

I've created a database and need to pass values to plot a graph. This is where I am having issues. Right now the graph is only showing but not plotting the values. Please help! Thanks

// MyDatabase

```
public class MyDatabase {

public static final String KEY_ROWID ="_id";
public static final String KEY_SYSTOLIC ="persons_systolic";
public static final String KEY_DIASTOLIC ="persons_diastolic";
public static final String KEY_PULSE ="persons_pulse";


private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "HealthDatabase";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "personsTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_SYSTOLIC + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_DIASTOLIC + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_PULSE + " TEXT NOT NULL);"

                        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }

}

 public MyDatabase(Context c){
     ourContext = c;

 }

 public MyDatabase open() throws SQLException{

        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;

    }

 public void close(){

     ourHelper.close();
 }

 public long createEntry(String sys, String dias, String pul) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_SYSTOLIC , sys);
    cv.put(KEY_DIASTOLIC, dias);
    cv.put(KEY_PULSE, pul);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

}

public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_SYSTOLIC,KEY_DIASTOLIC,KEY_PULSE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result =" ";

    //int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iSys = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SYSTOLIC);


    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){

        result = result + c.getString(iSys) + ",";

    }

    return result;

}
```

// MyActivity, this is where I am trying to plot a chart

```
 MyDatabase myDb = new MyDatabase(this);
         myDb.open();
         String pull = myDb.getData();
         pull = pull.substring(0, pull.length() - 1);
         myDb.close();

          double values = 3.0;

          int i = 0;

    //Here I don't know how to pass String pull in mSeries.
    // also the data in pull is 140, 156, 132

          mSeries.add(pull, values);

          SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
          renderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
          renderer.setColor(COLORS[(mSeries.getItemCount() - 1) % COLORS.length]);
         renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
          mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
         i++;
          mChartView = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(this, mSeries, mRenderer);
          LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Chart_layout);
          container.addView(mChartView);
```

Comment: change ur getData() method return type make it ArrayList<String>

Comment: Could you give an example on how to accomplish it?Thanks